# I am getting a syntax error trying to read in a CSV in Bash

Tags: linux, bash, rhel8

I have a bash script that I call in cron to do some daily data retrieval and reporting tasks. As part of the script, I read in a csv file that has business locations from where I need to run reports on. This was working without issue prior to a server migration but ever since then it I sporadically get syntax errors when running this script, always at the line where I tell bash where to get the csv for processing. The RHEL version on both the old server and the new server is 8.6.

Aside from that change, the only other thing that has changed in this part of the script is that in the old version I provided a literal path to the csv, whereas in the new version I'm calling supplying an ENV variable which provides the directory where data files reside.

```
while IFS="," read -r name division
do
  echo "Rendering report for $name"
  $HOME/render-doc.R -b $name -m $division -p Daily -s $start -e $end
done < <(cat $FILE_LOCATION/data.csv)
```

where $start and $end are POSIX time values calculated earlier in the script.

The "done" line is where bash says the syntax problem is. I've tried with "$FILE_LOCATION/data.csv", '$FILE_LOCATION/data.csv', and without quotes as written above. What's frustrating is that if I run this code snippet outside of the script, just at the prompt, it works fine. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: My guess is that the script is interpreted by a shell other than `bash`. The process substitution (the `<(...)` construct) is bash-specific. Anyway, it is not necessary in this case: Replace `<(cat $FILE_LOCATION/data.csv)` with `"$FILE_LOCATION/data.csv"`. Also you should quote your variable expansions.

Comment: I think you're right... when I took a closer look at what I copied out of my crontab, I noticed that somehow I had included "sh" between the ENV variable getting passed and calling the script. Removing that seems to have fixed the issue. But I will also take your advice and remove the process substitution call.

Comment: I think my reputation is too low to upvote answers, otherwise I'd recommend you make your comment an answer so I could accept it

Comment: That "other shell" should produce consistent failures, though, not sporadic.

Comment: You said "script that I call in cron" and "supplying an ENV variable". How are you passing the ENV variable into cron?

Comment: When I call the script in cron, the call is ```VAR=value command``` which functions like passing a variable to the script. I took out the "sh" and now the script runs without issue. I think it appeared "intermittent" because previous times running the script during testing I  correctly omitted calling the script via sh, but when i tested previously after noticing the cronjob was not working right, I ran by copy/pasting what was in the crontab.